# When does $\forall p: E_p[f] = E_p[g]$ imply $f = g$?

Tags: random-variable, expected-value, terminology, complete-statistics, steins-phenomenon

Let's say
$$E_p[f(X)] = E_p[g(X)]$$
for all $p \in S$, where $S$ might be some parametric family of densities, for instance. Under which assumptions on $S$ does this imply $f = g$?

I am reading [Efron & Morris (1973)](http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/nicholas.polson/teaching/41900/efron-morris2.pdf) and they talk about *completeness* of distributions implying equality of $f$ and $g$ (Equation 1.15), but I am not sure which notion of completeness they are referring to.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_(statistics) it's just a technical condition